# App Engine Endpoint Parameter with Array of different objects

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to call App Engine Endpoint with an Array of different objects, Say `String`, `int` and `int`.

I have tried couple of suggestions mentioned in StackOverflow, but those are not supporting as the Array of objects are of different types.

I have created a class `JsonList<T>` to save an object and `ContainerInfo` class holding `String`, `int` and `int` as members with `get` and `set` function calls.

When I try to call endpoint as `Endpoint(User, JsonList<ContainerInfo>)`, `IllegalArgumentException` `Parameterized type <ContainerInfo> not supported` error is thrown.

Is there a workaround possible to achieve this?

Comment: According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/parameter-and-return-types#supported_parameter_types) you may only use arrays or Collections. So your JsonList should implement the `java.util.Collection` interface.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is Endpoint methods won't let you pass in two or more objects (unless they are primitive types like String, etc.). In your example you are passing in `User` and `JsonList` objects.

What you can do is create a pojo wrapper class when doing that and inside there have the `User` object as well as your JsonList array there. Then inside your Endpoint method unwrap everything.

```
Endpoint(MyWrapper)
```

Note: your JsonList may or may not have to implement `Serializable` if you intent to call your Endpoints method from a mobile client like Android.

**EDIT:**
Here is an example:

```
public final class SomeObject
{
    private String stringValue;
    private int intValue;
    // add more 

    public SomeObject(String stringValue, int intValue)
    {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public String getString()
    {
        return stringValue;
    }

    public String getInt()
    {
        return intValue;
    }
}

public final class someObjectWrapper
{
    private User user;
    private List<SomeObject> someObjectList

    public someObjectWrapper(List<SomeObject> someObjectList, int user) {
        this.someObjectList = someObjectList;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<SomeObject> getSomeObjectList() {
        return someObjectList;
    }

    public void setSomeObjectList(List<SomeObject> someObjectList) {
        this.someObjectList = someObjectList;
    }

        public int getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(int user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Then inside your API method, just get those properties from the wrapper as new variables and then work with them however you want.

Comment: Thanks for sharing an update. I want to pass argument as {[String, int, int], [String, int, int], ...}. How to wrap and send this data in a single endpoint call?

Comment: I got the following exception when I try to load the page. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object type SomeObject not supported.`
 at com.google.api.server.spi.config.jsonwriter.JsonConfigWriter.addTypeToNode(JsonConfigWriter.java:668)

Comment: Is the Json parser expecting data in a different form?

Comment: I some how reached to next level but not yet solved the error. The page load is successful with Endpoint API defined as `public void saveObjectList(final someObjectWrapper objList)`. When the endpoint call was made, I got Json Mapping exception `com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class someObjectList]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)`

Comment: If I define a default constructor for `someObjectList` class, then `NullPointerException` was thrown when `getSomeObjectList()` was accessed. Somehow the Json mapping fails to put the data to the list.

Comment: Following is the code snippet of how the data is passed to Endpoint in AngularJS `var movieList = [];
listItems.push({
 stringValue: $scope.data,
 intValue1: 1,
 intValue2: 2
});
listItems.push({
 stringValue: $scope.data,
 intValue1: 2,
 intValue2: 4
});
EndpointAPI(listItems)`